# Android Design Support Library - toolbar transition

Tags: android, transition

I try to make android toolbar transition from recyclerview item name to toolbar title (text). I create it like Alex Lockwood [recommendation](https://plus.google.com/+AlexLockwood/posts/RPtwZ5nNebb). In appcompat-v7:22 all works fine, when I update to appcompat-v7:23 transition does't work.

Does somebody know whats happen with appcompat-v7:23?

My code (with appcompat-v7:22 all works fine):

```
private void startDataActivity(Activity activity, View toolbar,
                                   Category category) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            View decor = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            View statusBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
            View navBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground);

            List<Pair> participants = new ArrayList<>(3);
            participants.add(new Pair<>(toolbar, activity.getString(R.string.transition_toolbar)));
            addNonNullViewToTransitionParticipants(statusBar, participants);
            addNonNullViewToTransitionParticipants(navBar, participants);

            ActivityOptions sceneTransitionAnimation = ActivityOptions
                    .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
                            participants.toArray(new Pair[participants.size()]));

            final Bundle transitionBundle = sceneTransitionAnimation.toBundle();
            activity.startActivity(ShowCategoryActivity.getStartIntent(activity,
                    category.getId()), transitionBundle);
        } else {
            activity.startActivity(ShowCategoryActivity.getStartIntent(activity,
                    category.getId()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you see any warning or error in console/logs?

Comment: No error, activity starts, but without transition. Go back to appcompat-v7:22 and all works fine.